# Mapping an http request within subscribe()

Tags: angular, pipe, mapping, rxjs-observables

I see this question being asked a lot but I couldn't find a clear explanation that explains why my code doesn't work!

```
  getItemValueHistory(ids: number) {
this.itemResource.getItemValueHistory(ids).subscribe(
  (res: ItemItemValueHistory[]) => {
    res.forEach((itemHistory) => {
      const history = itemHistory.second.listOfPrices.map(values => values.currentPrice);
      const item = itemHistory.first;
      this.simpleCharts.push(this.createSimpleChart(item, history));
    });
  }
);}
```

So this function gits an array of ids for which it will fetch some values from the backend (I know the naming for the response is not very clear but this will all be fixed later).

On the HTML side of things there is an ngFor that loops over the array simpleCharts.

```
   <div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let simpleChart of simpleCharts">
    <app-simple-graph [simpleChart]="simpleChart"></app-simple-graph>
  </div>
```

The issue I'm having is when I try to split up the response I get from the backend into an item and a history part. The *map* on the history always fails because I cant read the undefined list. I thought that when I executed code within the subscribe this would only run when you get the observable?

Probably something very obvious I'm missing but would love to know what it is!

By suggestion of Alexander update code: this still gives me an TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined error at itemHistory.second.listOfPrices.map

```
  getItemValueHistory(ids: number) {
    this.itemResource.getItemValueHistory(ids)
      .pipe(
        map((itemHistories: ItemItemValueHistory[]) => {
          return itemHistories.map(itemHistory => {
            const history = itemHistory.second.listOfPrices.map(values => values.currentPrice);
            const item = itemHistory.first;
            return this.createSimpleChart(item, history);
          });
        })
      ).subscribe(res => {
      return this.simpleCharts.push(res);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saw this question open. Eventually this was a very noob mistake of not a correct mapping of the response to an object. I missed a letter and so it never got mapped and was always undefined, oops :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `simpleCharts` doesn't seem to be an `Observable<T>` and you aren't using something like `async` pipe that would wait for the `Observable` to emit. Try something like this, using RxJS `map` operator to create an array of charts using `Array.prototype.map`:

```
getItemValueHistory(ids: number) {
  return this.itemResource.getItemValueHistory(ids)
    .pipe(
      map((itemHistories: ItemItemValueHistory[]) => {
        return itemHistories.map(itemHistory => {
          const history = itemHistory.second.listOfPrices.map(values => values.currentPrice);
          const item = itemHistory.first;
          return this.createSimpleChart(item, history);
        });
      })
    );
}
```

Then you can either save that `Observable` to class property to use with `async` pipe:

```
<div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let simpleChart of simpleCharts$ | async ">
  <app-simple-graph [simpleChart]="simpleChart"></app-simple-graph>
</div>
```

Or `subscribe` to `getItemValueHistory` and update `this.simpleCharts` with the emitted mapped value, making sure to initialize `simpleCharts` to an empty array:

```
// make sure to initialize an empty array of the appropriate type
simpleCharts = [];

getItemValueHistory(ids: number) {
  this.itemResource.getItemValueHistory(ids)
    .pipe(
      map((itemHistories: ItemItemValueHistory[]) => {
        return itemHistories.map(itemHistory => {
          const history = itemHistory.second.listOfPrices.map(values => values.currentPrice);
          const item = itemHistory.first;
          return this.createSimpleChart(item, history);
        });
      })
    ).subscribe(res => this.simpleCharts = res);
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions. I had already tried the asynchronous ng for with observables route but I ran into the problem that the resource wouldn't be called at all anymore. This also happenned when I tried your first example.

The second example still gives me an error that the map is still undefined. This is one of the ways I tried the very first myself :).

**Function signature of createSimpleChart:
createSimpleChart(item: Item, itemHistory: number[]): ChartType**

Comment: @YvanStemmerik Can you please create an example at https://stackblitz.com/ or similar? You can simply mock the data (`itemResource.getItemValueHistory`) using RxJS to return an observable with `of` or `from`.